# Websocket in Spring Boot app - Getting 403 Forbidden

Tags: java, gradle, websocket, spring-boot, sockjs

Websocket in Spring Boot app - Getting 403 Forbidden

I can  connect to the websocket from client using sockjs/stompjs when I run this in eclipse (no spring boot).

But when I create a Spring boot jar(gradlew build) for the websocket code and run the java -jar websocket-code.jar I get a 403 error connecting to the websocket.

I have no authentication for the websockets. 
I have a CORS filters and think have all headers right in request/response.

Below is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE")
    }
}

configurations {
    compile.exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework:spring-web:$spring_version"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:$spring_version"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-websocket:$spring_version"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-messaging:$spring_version"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.2"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.2"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.6.2"
    compile "org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:1.3.5.RELEASE"
    compile("org.springframework:spring-tx")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.2.6.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:1.2.6.RELEASE")
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    testCompile "org.springframework:spring-test:$spring_version"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.5'
}
```

Update:

Added a CORS filter with
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8089");

In firebug on Client side

```
Request Headers 
Origin  
http://localhost:8089

Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
http://localhost:8089

Server Logs
2015-10-02 16:57:31.372 DEBUG 1848 --- [qtp374030679-14] o.s.w.s.s.t.h.DefaultSockJsService       : Request rejected, Origin header value http://localhost:8089 not allowed
```

Origin I am requesting from is in the Allow-origin list. Still getting Request Rejected message in the logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Difference between my 2 environment was the version of jars.

```
spring-boot-starter-websocket-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-websocket-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
```

Because of the spring-boot-starter-websocket dependency while packaging it was picking up spring-websocket-4.1.7.RELEASE inspite of the spring_version being spring_version=4.0.6.RELEASE.

Modified the dependency in build.gradle that fixed the problem.

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket:1.1.0.RELEASE"
```

I think in latest version of spring-websocket jar the class StompWebSocketEndpointRegistration has setAllowedOrigins method that has to be used.Have not tried this.

But CORS filter with

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8089");
```

is working with older version.

Comment: Not sure if these still works anymore. For me its saying the web socket layer requires credentials to be true and even when i put my set my allow origins in the CORS. I still get a 403 forbidden

Comment: in spring boot mvn, I just update same version and it worked: https://www.stackextend.com/angular/websocket-with-spring-boot-and-angular/
ver: 2.0.7.RELEASE

Answer (score 95):

I had a similar issue and fixed it in the WebSocketConfig by setting the allowed origins to "*".

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        // the endpoint for websocket connections
        registry.addEndpoint("/stomp").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

    // remaining config not shown as not relevant
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think setAllowedOrigins has been added to StompWebSocketEndpointRegistration in new release. I think your solution should work in new release. I am using as older websocket jar.

Comment: isn't it insecure to use such a wildcard for allowedOrigins ?

Comment: Thank you, my initial idea was to set the allowed origins in my WebMvcConfigurerAdapter for CORS. This worked though!

Comment: @niilzon, that depends on the operation purpose. Generally speaking I would rather agree with you. But you can simply exchange the wildcard with specific hosts like `setAllowedOrigins("http://somehost")`. That might seem pretty clear but I felt the urge to state it when stumbling on this post :-)

Comment: where can we locate this file?

Comment: Note that this works as well for raw web sockets registered in `WebSocketConfigurer`. In method `public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {}` you can call `registry.addHandler(new MyWebSocketHandler(), "/some-path").setAllowedOrigins("*");`. It's unfortunate that WebSocket is not able to tell you that it's a CORS problem... 403 is quite misleading.

Answer (score 6):

try to add

```
registry.addEndpoint("/your-end-point").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
```

"your-end-point" is registered by @SendTo in controller I guess

Comment: Wow, been hung up on this for several hours and this was the fix. The latest spring security 6 websocket docs don't cover it and error handling doesnt indicate this issue, nor do I see anything CORS related in the browser that is failing.

Answer (score 6):

For reference, newer versions of spring require a different method:

```
registry.addEndpoint("/websocket-connection").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS();
```